# A strange question: price is $0.68000000000000005

Tags: price, product-prices, rounding, magento2.2-dev

My Magento2 is ver. 2.2.0-dev. 
When I set product's price to `$0.68`, after save the price will be `$0.68000000000000005`.
But when the price is `$0.5`, it's ok.

Comment: have you checked this in an official/stable release, e.g. v2.1.6? Maybe it's a 2.2.0 development bug

Answer (score 1):

Within the 2.2.0-dev  'app/bootstrap.php' there are below lines. The precision sets the number of decimal places being used by php so setting this to 2 should change the decimal places used:

```
/*  Adjustment of precision value for several versions of PHP */
ini_set('precision', 17);
ini_set('serialize_precision', 17);
```

Change to:

```
/*  Adjustment of precision value for several versions of PHP */
ini_set('precision', 2);
ini_set('serialize_precision', 2);
```

You could also set the price variable to show just 2 decimal places with below from within your template:

```
echo number_format($product->getPrice(), '2', '.', ',')
```